# link for XAML WPF documentation which describes elements/attributes

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm after a link to online Microsoft reference doco for the XAML elements/attributes that are used in WPF XAML?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such list would be pointless, because most tags can be used only in certain context.

All elements inherit from  [FrameworkElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.aspx) class (though there are many more non-element tags, but these are usually used in specific contexts only), so you can look them up from there (though some of the children are abstract). Each tag's class page also contains information which tags it can contain.

Btw, IntelliSense is very helpful in this case. Just hit Ctrl + Shift and you get list of all the tags you can use in the context.

Also, you may want to check Expression Blend, it has siginificantly better XAML designer than Visual Studio (and it offers much more elements on the palette). And it works well together with Visual Studio (as long as you have corresponding version - Expression 3 vs. VS 2008 / Expression 4 vs. VS 2010).

Comment: ok I think I see what you mean - but HTML & CSS is a little the same and there are some reasonable sites out there that help you make sense for a particular element the various attributes.   Thanks for the Expression Blend pointer.  Actually I'm using WPF Toolkit for charting, and I note the chart itself doesn't turn up in the VS2010 editor (just the window which it sits in).  I wonder if Blend would help out here...

Comment: AS I said - you can see all the basic elements in the list of FrameworkElement children. But if you wanted the list of all useable tags, you would have to go to a DependecyObject's list of children.